# erlang : get the value for the set of keys from proplists

Tags: list, loops, search, erlang

I have "difficult" proplists. I need to get to `serviceCatalog` and traverse all its values untill I get one having name=`me`

```
J =[{<<"access">>,
      {[{<<"token">>,
         {[{<<"issued_at">>,<<"2015-09-12T13:27:38.789879">>},
           {<<"expires">>,<<"2015-09-12T14:27:38Z">>},
           {<<"id">>,<<"fe">>},
           {<<"tenant">>,
            {[{<<"description">>,null},
              {<<"enabled">>,true},
              {<<"id">>,<<"01">>},
              {<<"name">>,<<"service">>}]}},
           {<<"audit_ids">>,[<<"f">>]}]}},
        {<<"serviceCatalog">>,
         [{[{<<"endpoints">>,
             [{[{<<"adminURL">>,<<"http://8.198.99.999:8080">>},
                {<<"region">>,<<"RegionOne">>},
                {<<"internalURL">>,
                 <<"http://8.198.99.999:8080/v1/AUTH_01a"...>>},
                {<<"id">>,<<"30">>},
                {<<"publicURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v1/"...>>}]}]},
            {<<"endpoints_links">>,[]},
            {<<"type">>,<<"object-store">>},
            {<<"name">>,<<"my">>}]},
          {[{<<"endpoints">>,
             [{[{<<"adminURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v2.0">>},
                {<<"region">>,<<"RegionOne">>},
                {<<"internalURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v2.0">>},
                {<<"id">>,<<"4b3f44a5c64b4bd8b10c376c858b"...>>},
                {<<"publicURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080"...>>}]}]},
            {<<"endpoints_links">>,[]},
            {<<"type">>,<<"identity">>},
            {<<"name">>,<<"other">>}]}]},
        {<<"user">>,
         {[{<<"username">>,<<"my">>},
           {<<"roles_links">>,[]},
           {<<"id">>,<<"8">>},
           {<<"roles">>,[{[{<<"name">>,<<"admin">>}]}]},
           {<<"name">>,<<"me">>}]}},
        {<<"metadata">>,
         {[{<<"is_admin">>,0},
           {<<"roles">>,
            [<<"e">>]}]}}]}}]
```

I am looking for the nice way to do it.
I started the implementation like that (but looks that there more elegant solution):

```
A1=proplists:get_value(<<"access">>,J).
A=element(1,A1).
B=proplists:get_value(<<"token">>, A).
C=element(1,B).
D=proplists:get_value(<<"serviceCatalog">>, C).
```

Any advices are wellcome

Comment: Please clarify the problem; are you saying that you want to find all tuples in this data with a key `<<"serviceCatalog">>` whose value contains somewhere within it a tuple with the value `{<<"name">>, <<"me">>}`, and do you want the whole `<<"serviceCatalog">>` tuple returned if  `{<<"name">>, <<"me">>}` is found? And BTW if this is what you want, please note that your example data doesn't match, since  `{<<"name">>, <<"me">>}` exists only within the `{<<"user">>, ...}` tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how deeply nested the data is, one approach is to write a set of recursive function clauses that can find a 2-tuple with a given key regardless of its level in the data. Here's an example:

```
-module(t).
-export([extract/2]).

extract(Key, Data) ->
    extract(Key, Data, []).
extract(_Key, [], Acc) ->
    Acc;
extract(Key, {Key,_}=KV, Acc) ->
    [KV|Acc];
extract(Key, [{Key,_}=KV|Fields], Acc) ->
    extract(Key, Fields, [KV|Acc]);
extract(Key, [{_,V}|Fields], Acc) when is_tuple(V); is_list(V) ->
    extract(Key, Fields, extract(Key, V, Acc));
extract(Key, Data, Acc) when is_list(Data) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(V, FoldAcc) when is_tuple(V); is_list(V) ->
                        extract(Key, V, FoldAcc);
                   (_, FoldAcc) ->
                        FoldAcc
                end, Acc, Data);
extract(Key, Data, Acc) when is_tuple(Data) ->
    extract(Key, tuple_to_list(Data), Acc).
```

The `extract/2` function just passes its arguments along with an empty accumulator list to `extract/3`. The clauses of `extract/3` work as described below:

- The first clause checks if the data is an empty list, and if so, returns the accumulator.
- The second clause matches the desired `Key` as the first element of a 2-tuple and adds that matching tuple to the accumulator.
- The third clause matches the desired `Key` as the first element of a 2-tuple at the head of a list. It adds that matching tuple to the accumulator and continues extracting from other elements of the list.
- The fourth clause handles the case of a 2-tuple without a matching key at the head of a list, where the value in the tuple is either a list or a tuple; if so, it attempts extraction from the value, and then continues with extracting from the rest of the list.
- The fifth clause matches when `Data` is a list that doesn't match lists already matched by previous clauses. It folds over all values of the list, attempting extraction from all nested list and tuple values and ignoring all other values.
- The sixth and final clause matches when `Data` is a tuple; it just converts the tuple to a list and calls `extract/3` recursively.

Given the data `J` defined in the question, we can find a 2-tuple with a `<<"serviceCatalog">>` key like this:

```
1> SCs = t:extract(<<"serviceCatalog">>, J).
[{<<"serviceCatalog">>,
  [{[{<<"endpoints">>,
      [{[{<<"adminURL">>,<<"http://8.198.99.999:8080">>},
         {<<"region">>,<<"RegionOne">>},
         {<<"internalURL">>,
          <<"http://8.198.99.999:8080/v1/AUTH_01a">>},
         {<<"id">>,<<"30">>},
         {<<"publicURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v1/">>}]}]},
     {<<"endpoints_links">>,[]},
     {<<"type">>,<<"object-store">>},
     {<<"name">>,<<"my">>}]},
   {[{<<"endpoints">>,
      [{[{<<"adminURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v2.0">>},
         {<<"region">>,<<"RegionOne">>},
         {<<"internalURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080/v2.0">>},
         {<<"id">>,<<"4b3f44a5c64b4bd8b10c376c858b">>},
         {<<"publicURL">>,<<"8.198.99.999:8080">>}]}]},
     {<<"endpoints_links">>,[]},
     {<<"type">>,<<"identity">>},
     {<<"name">>,<<"other">>}]}]}]
```

The extraction found the element we expected. We can then pass that to further calls to `t:extract/2` to see if the element we found contains the `<<"name">>` element we're seeking. We'll use a list comprehension that returns a list of tuples, each holding a `<<"serviceCatalog">>` element and a boolean indicating whether it contains the desired `<<"name">>` element:

```
2> [{SC,lists:any(fun({_, V}) -> V == <<"me">> end, t:extract(<<"name">>, SC))} || SC <- SCs].
```

The list comprehension walks over all the `<<"serviceCatalog">>` elements, extracting all `<<"name">>` tuples from each one and checking for any with a value of `<<"me">>`.

Unfortunately the `<<"serviceCatalog">>` element in the example data does not have a `{<<"name">>, <<"me">>}` tuple as described in the question, so the boolean in the result of the above list comprehension (the result is not shown) is `false`. But either way, to walk the result of the list comprehension, keep only the `true` values, but strip out the booleans so the resulting list contains only matching `<<"serviceCatalog">>` elements, we can fold over the list. First, let's make a fold function:

```
3> Fold = fun({SC, true}, Acc) -> [SC|Acc]; (_, Acc) -> Acc end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.54118792>
```

Our fold function takes each `{SC, boolean}` tuple, adds those with `true` values to the accumulator list, and drops those with `false` values. Below we capture the result of the list comprehension from earlier, then pass it and the fold function to `lists:foldl/3`:

```
4> SCBools = [{SC,lists:any(fun({_, V}) -> V == <<"me">> end, t:extract(<<"name">>, SC))} || SC <- SCs].
...
5> lists:foldl(Fold, [], SCBools).
[]
```

Again, since no `<<"serviceCatalog">>` element in the data contains a `{<<"name">>, <<"me">>}` tuple, the resulting list here is empty, but if any did, we'd get their values in the list returned from `lists:foldl/3`.